# Can't sign in to Xcode in the latest MacOS beta

Tags: xcode, macos-big-sur

I'm unable to sing in to my AppleID in Xcode. I'm on the newest MacOS Big Sur beta. Every time I sign in I get the error: `Your session has expired. Please Log in`. I tried everything I could think of: I tried a different AppleId, I reinstalled Xcode and I restartet my Mac. Nothing helped.

Comment: is your Apple ID sing in browser 
which Xcode version you use

Comment: Same problem here. I can log in normally via web to appstoreconnect and developer.apple but not to xcode (11.7). I'm also on Big Sur.

Comment: Having the same issue here.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?